# Is there a way to use regex to perform the same image swap function regardless of extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

There must be, right? Maybe I just don't know enough about how to effectively use regex and/or jQuery, but I had originally written a little function to handle some image swapping when hovering over images on the page (not CSS background-images):

```
$('.footer-show-hide a img, #rfq-cta img').hover(function () {
   var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "_hover.png");
   $(this).attr("src", src);
  }, function(){
   var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_hover.png", ".png");
   $(this).attr("src", src);
 });
```

So this worked great and since, up until this point, all images had been .png, I didn't need to worry about anything else. However, other assets were provided and are in .jpg format. While I could easily open Photoshop and re-save them as .png, I'd rather have a more useful/elastic function that behaves the same way regardless of file extension.

I tried a few common regular expressions for validating image extensions, but none of them worked. Again, I might not just know how to properly use them, but I gave up after about 20 minutes of tinkering and instead modified the function to be this:

```
$('.footer-show-hide a img, #rfq-cta img, article.blog-post.homepage p.register img').hover(function () {
    var ext = $(this).attr("src").split('.').pop();
    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("." + ext, "_hover." + ext);
    $(this).attr("src", src);
  }, function(){
    var ext = $(this).attr("src").split('.').pop();
    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_hover." + ext, "." + ext);
    $(this).attr("src", src);
  });
```

(the image in 'article.blog-post.homepage p.register img' being the one that's a jpg)

It works exactly how I want it to, but this doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing but by using a regex to either ignore the extension entirely and append/remove '_hover' as needed or to accept any extension and replace it with the same extension when adding/removing '_hover'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work, assuming your filenames do not have periods in them (do they? If so, you'll want to match up until the last occurrence of a period in the first capture group).

```
/([^\.]+)\.([\w]+)$/
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/([^\.]+)\.([\w]+)/, "$1_hover.$2");
```

and replacing it back could use:

```
/([^\.]+)_hover\.([\w]+)$/
```

and the code would look like:

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/([^\.]+)_hover\.([\w]+)/, "$1.$2");
```

**EDIT:** Learning that these are fully-qualified URLs instead of relative paths, I've added an end-of-string check to the regex

Comment: Thank you! So I tried this out and it's half-working...it works with the jpg, but not with the .pngs for some reason. 

Checking the URL of the actual image I know is there and what's being output, the regex is adding _hover to the dev server subdomain which is causing the error.

xxxx-dev.xxxx.com 

is becoming

xxxx-dev_hover.xxxx.com

So I need to match only with the last period. I found a few solutions, but,they aren't working when I paste them into what you provided above. I was using (?=[^.]*$) to give:
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/([^\.(?=[^.]*$)]+)\.([\w]+)/, "$1_hover.$2");

Comment: ...and that doesn't work. It gives this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([^\.(?=[^.]*$)]+)\.([\w]+)/: Unmatched ')'

So, again, I clearly don't know what I'm doing with this. :-/

Comment: So in that example, you'd want `xxxx-dev.xxxx.com` to become `xxxx-dev.xxxx_hover.com`?

Comment: No, that's what it IS happening right now. It's adding that _hover to the URL for some reason, only with .png files. The .jpg works fine. I just want it to apply this regex to the final period in the image URL (which will be the one before the image extension).

Comment: Ok, can you provide a valid JPG URL and what it should become, as well as a PNG URL in your question? This should help shed some light on the proper regex

Comment: Sure. Here's a regular .png: http://topfloortech-dev.topfloortech.com/sites/all/themes/topfloor/images/request_a_quote.png and here's what it should be on hover: http://topfloortech-dev.topfloortech.com/sites/all/themes/topfloor/images/request_a_quote_hover.png but what's happening is http://topfloortech-dev_hover.topfloortech.com/sites/all/themes/topfloor/images/request_a_quote.png

Comment: Those URLs are password protected :) but I've posted up modified regexs to try

Comment: Okay, as I was doing this, I realized that the two .pngs in question have full URLs for the the src whereas the jpg has a relative url (/sites/all/themes/topfloor/images/cta_register_ribbon.jpg) and THAT is why the jpg is working but the .pngs are not.

Comment: Please try the modified regexs above (note the additional `$`s at the end)